# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor - Windows Authentication Failing Every Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've been fighting this issue for far to long. Basically, I'm building a corporate intranet site (first one in MVC 3) and I cannot get any authorization checks to function. Even the basic "Intranet" project type fails to work. Interestingly, the "Welcome domain\username" works fine so I know that it is getting partial AD info.

Here is my process for the most basic setup that is failing:

Login as domain user on a Windows 7 development workstation

Using VS2010 fully patched -> Create New Project -> ASP.NET MVC 3 -> Intranet Application

Right Click Project -> Use IIS Express

Properties of Project -> Disable Anonymous Access, Enable Windows Authentication

Modify web.config to add:

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
```

Verify web.config contains:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />

<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Modify default HomeController  where Group1 and Group2 are verified and working groups in other applications:

**HomeController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVC3AuthTest001.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            Boolean isAdmin01 = User.IsInRole("Group1");
            Boolean isAdmin02 = User.IsInRole("Group2");

            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!" + " Admin: " + isAdmin01 + " EACAdmin: " + isAdmin02;

            return View();
        }

     }
 }
```

Run the code and the following is displayed:

**Welcome to ASP.NET MVC! Group1: False Group2: False**

Both should be true since I am member of both groups.

In addition all

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Group1")]
```

Verifications fail in the main application resulting in empty screens.

I would normally assume a network issue, but the same code running in an MVC 2 application works exactly as expected with the groups.

Deploying the application to our development server (production configuration, IIS 7 on Win2008 Server) also fails to work as expected.

I'm at wit's end...

Is there some step that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would first take a look at the following: what does [`Roles.GetRolesForUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.getrolesforuser.aspx) return? This should be `Group1` and `Group2` but is probably something else.

Second, you may want to check that you actually see a [`WindowsIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx) as the authenticated identity. Check that [`Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.identity.aspx) is a `WindowsIdentity` and not something else.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

GetRolesForUser does contain the role in question, and the Thread is a WindowsIdentity with my credentials and "isAuthenticated = True".

Now I'm more confused than before, because obviously my credentials are available to the applicaiton.

Comment: Hm, that's weird. So you use the *exact* same role names? Maybe worth an attempt (I remember having seen this somewhere): use `CN=Group1` as a role name. I have no ideas what else could be wrong.